# How do I align a character in a string with the new f formatting?

Tags: python

Say something like this:

```
print(f"Apples: ")
print(f"Bananas: ")
print(f"Potatoes: ")
```

How do I make it so that the colon of each line is lined up? I want the output like this:

```
Apples  :
Bananas :
Potatoes:
```

I tried the right justification but that didn't give the desired result.

Comment: `print(f"Apples  :")`?!

Comment: Yes I realized I can just have spaces but is there any way to do it automatically in the formatting?

Comment: Explain the use case, is the string dynamic or fixed to Apples, Bananas, and Potatoes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
print(f"{'Apples':8}: ")
print(f"{'Bananas':8}: ")
print(f"{'Potatoes':8}: ")
```

Output:

```
Apples  : 
Bananas : 
Potatoes:
```

Comment: @Molessia Won't work if length of words are greater than 8

Comment: Getting `ValueError: Invalid format specifier` on Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\r` carriage return in the following way:

```py
Len=len("Potatoes")
print(' '*Len+":\rApples")
print(' '*Len+":\rBananas")
print(' '*Len+":\rPotatoes")
```

For info about `\r` search the net.

Comment: That doesn't give the expected result

Comment: Yes, one need to adjust the gap. The expected result will be returned if `\t\t` will be relplaced by `' '*len(potatoes)`